# Mongo find documents where value of property does not contains a given string

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to find all document where `food` does not contains 'hot' case insensitive.

`FoodCol.find({food: /^hot/});` is not cutting it.

So that I need the code to only return `{food: 'chicken soup, type: 'soups'}` sine it is the only document where the string 'hot' is not found in the property 'food'.
How can it be done? Thanks

```
{
  {
    food: 'Hot coffee',
    type: 'drink'
  }, {
    food: 'cake with hot topping',
    type: 'cake'
  }, {
    food: 'chicken soup',
    type: 'soups'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the following query, it uses the **[`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/)** operator which will perform a logical NOT operation on the regex specified and selects the documents that do not match the regex:

```
FoodCol.find({ "food": { "$not": /hot/i } })
```